# Using front-page.php need new blog page

Tags: menus, frontpage

I'm using front-page.php to generate a static frontpage for a Web site I'm working on. I can't seem to get Wordpress to display the blog posts on any other page. I tried creating a custom template to display blog posts, but it doesn't display any posts. Also, when I try to set the front-page as a static frontpage manually in the reading settings, it doesn't appear as an option. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a static Front Page, you need to do the following:

1. Create two *static Pages*, one for your front page content, and one for your blog posts index; their names are entirely arbitrary, but for our purposes, let's call them "Front Page" and "Blog"
2. Go to `Dashboard -> Settings -> Reading`
3. Set "Front Page Displays" to "static page"
4. In the dropdown lists below, set "front page" to "Front Page", and "posts page" to "Blog"

Now, for some explanation:

- WordPress will use your `front-page.php` template file when rendering your site front page, whether the front page is set to display blog posts or a static Page.
- If you want to customize your blog posts index, use the `home.php` template, which will be used when a *static Page* is used to display blog posts, or when the *front page* is set to display blog posts *if no `front-page.php` template file exists*.
- If neither of these two template files exist, then WordPress will fall back to:

  - `page.php`, for a static front page, or for blog posts if set to display on a *static Page*
  - `index.php` in all other cases

If you still need some clarification, see the [Codex entry for Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).